# How can I calculate this integral by hand?

Tags: calculus, integration

In solving this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526997/how-to-prove-that-iint-fracy2s2-dy-ds-4), I come up with the following integral:

$$\int_{-1/(4\pi)}^0\frac{(s\log{(-4\pi s)})^{(2+n)/2}}{s^2}ds$$

where $n=1,2,3...$

By using Mathematica, I could get that the integral is equal to $$\frac{8\pi^{-n/2}\Gamma(2+n/2)}{2^{1+n/2}n^{(4+n)/2}}$$

My question is: How do we calculate it by hand? Is there any clever way to do it?

Comment: It seems like you can factor out a lot of constants for starters - that may make things easier.

Comment: After throwing away the constants, you're left with $$\int_{-1/(4\pi)}^0\!\!\!\frac {(s\log (-4\pi s))^{1+n/2}}{s^2}\,ds.$$ Still not too pretty

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite your integral as $$\frac{(2n)^{1+n/2}}{2+n}\int_{-1/(4\pi)}^{0}s^{-1+n/2}[\log(-4\pi s)]^{1+n/2}ds$$
Then make the substitution $u=\log(-4\pi s),$ giving $du=1/s$ and $s^{n/2}=(-\frac{1}{4\pi} e^{u})^{n/2}$. Your limits become $0$ (upper) and $-\infty$ (lower) - switch them, using up a minus sign. The gamma function should become very apparent.

**Note**: You should be much more careful than I have been with minus signs in logarithms and square roots. This is purely a sketch to give you some ideas.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{{\rm e}^{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}$

\begin{align}
&\overbrace{\int_{-1/\pars{4\pi}}^{{0}}{%
\bracks{s\log{\pars{-4\pi s}}}^{\pars{2 + n}/2}
 \over
 s^{2}}\,\dd s}^{\ds{s\ =\ -\,{x \over 4\pi}\,,\quad x = -4\pi s}}\
=\
\pars{-1}^{\pars{n/2} -1}\,\,{\pi^{-n/2} \over 2^{n}}\quad
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}x^{\pars{n/2} - 1}\ln^{\pars{n/2} + 1}\pars{x}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{x\ =\ \expo{-z}\,,\quad z = -\ln\pars{x}}}
\\[3mm]&=
\pars{-1}^{\pars{n/2} - 1}\,\,
{\pi^{-n/2} \over 2^{n}}\,\pars{-1}^{\pars{n/2} + 1}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-nz/2}\,z^{\pars{n/2} + 1}\,\dd z
\\[3mm]&=
\pars{-1}^{n}\,\,{\pi^{-n/2} \over 2^{n}}\,{1 \over \pars{n/2}^{\pars{n/2} + 2}}
\quad
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-z}\,z^{\bracks{\pars{n/2} + 2} - 1}\,\dd z}
^{\ds{\Gamma\pars{{n \over 2} + 2}}}
\\[3mm]&=
\pars{-1}^{n}\,\,{\pi^{-n/2} \over 2^{-2 + \pars{n/2}}}\,
{1 \over n^{\pars{n/2} + 2}}\Gamma\pars{2 + {n \over 2}}
=
\pars{-1}^{n}\,\,{8\pi^{-n/2} \over 2^{1 + \pars{n/2}}}\,
{1 \over n^{\pars{4 + n}/2}}\Gamma\pars{2 + {n \over 2}}
\\[1cm]&
\end{align}

$$
{\large\int_{-1/\pars{4\pi}}^{{0}}{%
\bracks{s\log{\pars{-4\pi s}}}^{\pars{2 + n}/2}
 \over
 s^{2}}\,\dd s
=
\color{#ff0000}{\large%
\pars{-1}^{n}\,
{8\pi^{-n/2}\,\Gamma\pars{2 + n/2}
 \over
 2^{1 + n/2\,}n^{\pars{4 + n}/2}}}}
$$
Notice that we got a pre factor $\pars{-1}^{n}$ besides the result the OP reports from the Mathematica package. We check explicitly ( we started from the initial integral with $n = 1$ ) our result for $n = 1$ and we found it's negative !!!.
We would like the OP recheck it with Mathematica ( Sorry, I don't have Mathematica ).

Comment: Are you sure that your calculation is correct?

Comment: @Pedro I'll check everything. 0 k.

Comment: @Pedro I recheck everything from the very beginning. I got the prefactor $\left(-1\right)^{n}$. Read my comment at the end of the calculation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made the changes that you suggested and it seems that worked. However, I made all changes before factor out the constants. So, we get 

$$\int_{-1/(4\pi)}^0\frac{(s\log{(-4\pi s)})^{(2+n)/2}}{s^2}\,ds$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{\left((-x/4\pi)\ln x\right)^{n/2+1}}{(-x/4\pi)^2}(-1/(4\pi)\,dx$$

$$=\int_0^\infty \frac{((-\exp({-z})/4\pi)(-z))^{n/2+1}}{(-\exp({-z})/4\pi)^2}(-1/(4\pi)(-\exp({-z}))\,dz$$

$$=\frac{8\pi^{-n/2}\Gamma(2+n/2)}{2^{1+n/2}n^{(4+n)/2}}$$

Comment: I think that in your solution, the error comes up in the second equality, when you uses $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ with $a,b<0$ ([this can be dangerous](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461695/starting-with-frac-11-frac1-1-and-taking-square-root-proves-1-1)). Notice that after you make the two changes this problem disappears.

Comment: @Pedro I'll check tomorrow because it's too late ( 4:30 in the morning ). Thanks.

Comment: @Pedro In my second checking ( with $n = 1$ ), I have the feeling the problem could be related to $n$ odd character.

Comment: Maybe you are right, because it seems that my calculation above is wrong too. I'll check it (again).

Comment: @FelixMarin, thank you for your help. Note that the integrand is positive, hence, the answer must be positive.

Comment: @Tomás I'll remove the factor later. I'm so busy now. Thanks.

Comment: I have posted a compilation of the calculation [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2226682/70305).